# Shared Memory on Windows

Tags: python, c++, qt, shared-memory

I have following problem. I have a python service streaming a lot of data.
I have c++ program whih I want to process the data with.

I tried to create a shared memory segment with windows API, but I was unable to find it from python.

I also tried `QSharedMemory` from Qt, but I cannot find the shared memory in the other program.

Could you please point me to some example where this is done ?
Thank you very much.
My c++ code:

```
#include <QSharedMemory>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QSharedMemory memory("shm");
    memory.create(10);
    memory.attach();
    return 0;
}
```

My python code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSharedMemory

memory = QSharedMemory("shm")
```

Comment: You can consider to use pipes, or even sockets instead. Sockets are quite fast between processes on the same PC, and it will enable you in the future to distribute your processing easily. Shared memory is very low level and you'll probably have to implement some message queues yourself. But the suitability of course depends on your required bandwidth.

Comment: What is not working? The code you provide doesn't test anything. You don't even check the return values. Please provide a reproducible example of your problem.

Comment: Sorry. I stop the c++ program with debugger (or with sleep) after create. I check in python memory.isAttached() but it is False.

Comment: You have to call `attach()` for it to be attached.

Comment: Take the time to read a bit about each method in https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsharedmemory.html. Basically `create()` will create and attach to a new segment in the system but won't attach to an existing one, while `attach()` will attach to an existing segment in the system but won't create one.

Comment: While I'm here: depending on how familiar you are with shared memory, you might want to use something easier first, like pipes as the first comment suggested. If you want to use shared memory, you will need synchronization to avoid data race conditions. For example you can use the integrated semaphore in QSharedMemory (lock/unlock methods), or with your own QSystemSemaphore if you need something more flexible.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that.